# sqlsrv PHP Returns Must declare the scalar variable "@P1"

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

so i'm trying in `PHP` to insert new members into a sql database with `sqlsrv`.
we had a facebook login working BUT that now also doesn't work anymore as the query reaches the database, executes it and returns

> "Must declare the scalar variable "@P1"

```
$NewMemberRegisterSQL = "INSERT INTO dbo.members (MemberName, MemberPassword, MemberEmail) VALUES(?,?,?)";
            $paramsNewMember = array($_POST['register-username'], $hashedPass, $_POST['register-email']);
            $InsertResult = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $NewMemberRegisterSQL, $paramsNewMember);
```

The Database exists of `MemberID` which is an auto increment, `FacebookID` which is allowed to be `null`,`MemberName` which is just the `username`,`MemberPassword` well guess what this one is, and `Memberemail`.
`FacebookID`,`Memberpassword` and `memberemail` are allowed to be `NULL`.

Comment: So what has changed since it was working?

Comment: almost nothing, The only thing that changed was that i tested my register and that somehow messed up the whole system, we got the Facebook login running again by changing the MemberID to an int with Identity Specification

Comment: "somehow messed up" isn't going to get us very far. We can't see what happened. What exactly did it do? Why did changing to an identity int (with, I assume, auto-increment as well?) fix it? What were you doing before instead of that? On the face of it I can't see anything obviously wrong with the snippet of code you've posted.

Comment: That's the problem, i can't seem to find anything that went wrong, First the memberID was a uniqueidentifyer, that worked with the facebook login the day before, this morning it worked, then i tested my register form and that messed it up to a point where the facebook login also did not work anymore

Comment: maybe the facebook login code is trying to write a uniqueidentifier into your members table, but now it is an auto-generated int? I don't know, there's not enough context here to know, we can't see the registration form, or the bit which handles facebook logins. Can someone register using a facebook account _or_ make an account directly? Do they use the same form for that, or a different one? Do you write the details into the same table? Lots of pieces of the puzzle are missing. And it's still really unclear how any of it relates to the code above or how the error message comes from that code

Comment: if you login using a Facebook login you can login, that works 100%, making an account directly does not work as that gives the error in the Database, the data goes into the exact same Table as the facebook details. Facebook is not writing anthing into MemberID as that is just an auto increment INT neither is the register form, the only thing different about the Facebook login/register and the Normal register is that the normal register also sends a hashed password into Memberpassword and the normal register does not send a FacebookID to the database

Comment: Update: If i copy the statement and i paste it manually into a query and then run it, it actually places it in the database, the MemberID also has gone up for every try we did. so it jumped up from 1 to 3 where we id the first one by hand, then tested the register(did not place it in the database) then tested the register again, copying the statement and placing it in the query which gave the ID 3 instead of 2

Comment: have you perhaps got some SQL Trigger which is executing after this insert? Try running SQL Server Profiler and see what the final query being sent to the database by the PHP actually looks like, and whether anything else tries to run afterwards.

Comment: exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO dbo.members (MemberName, MemberPassword, MemberEmail) VALUES(@P1,@P2,@P3)',N'@P1 varchar(8000),@P2 varchar(8000),@P3 varchar(8000)','jeremeyiseenhoer','$2y$10$zZuXX26jq6fbtY2Ls.UqweNLkRRUXkvcLV/JLYDjbEleGcSoxWLFy','zoekeenleven@nietschelden.nll' This is the query i get from the profiler

Comment: There is no other query or trigger being sent after this